# Inheriting EF class throws foreign key error in project using multiple data contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I apologize on the title as I'm not sure how to summarize the issue we are having in one sentence.

We have two solutions, one of our old code base, another with our latest and greatest, with both solutions sharing a project of code first EF models. The old solution also has another project of older EF models and its own database context. The old code worked with this blend of old and new until I added new classes that inherited an EF one. In our new system, CRUD operations work as expected with the sub classes, but on our old system we get this error:

> The entity types 'DiscountActivity' and 'DiscountSeries' cannot share table 'Discounts' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

Here are the classes in question:

```
[Table("Discounts")]
public class Discount
{
    [Column("Id"), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Column("Amount")]
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

public class DiscountActivity : Discount
{
    [Column("TypeId")]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }

    public DiscountActivity()
    {
        Type = "Activity";
    }
}

public class DiscountSeries : Discount
{
    [Column("TypeId")]
    public int SeriesId { get; set; }

    public virtual Series Series { get; set; }

    public DiscountSeries()
    {
        Type = "Series";
    }
}

[Table("Activities")]
public class Activity
{
    [Column("Id"), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DiscountActivity> Discounts { get; set; }
}

[Table("Series")]
public class Series
{
    [Column("Id"), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DiscountSeries> Discounts { get; set; }
}
```

If I comment out both ICollection lines in Activity and Series, the error no longer occurs. If I leave one of the two, does not matter which, the error still does not occur. Also, it does not seem to matter if the new or old EF database context is used for the LINQ statements when the ICollection objects are both present, the same error is thrown. So to be clear, when running a LINQ statement on the old database context, we get the above error even though models and collections are in a separate database context.

Here is an example in our old API using the old context:

```
public class ContractsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _db = new DatabaseContext();

    [ResponseType(typeof(Contract))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var model = _db.Contracts.Find(id);
        if (model == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: All this about old/new/blended is irrelevant as long as you don't show what it means in terms of code. The classes you show don't cause any conflict when used in one context.

Comment: Added an example, but please let me know what more you would like to see.